# Auto-complete for user defined functions

Tags: front-end, symbols, contexts, autocomplete

If I define a symbol in Mathematica, it doesn't show up in the autocomplete list that works for symbols in `System`.

Test code:

```
foo = 1;
bar[x_] := x + 1
$ContextPath
Context@foo
Context@bar
(* =>
     {Notebook$$35$859131`, System`}
     Notebook$$35$859131`
     Notebook$$35$859131`
*)
```

Neither `foo` nor `bar` will show up in the autocomplete list.

Is it possible to make `foo` and `bar` show up in this list, without defining them in the `System` context?

**Edit:**

It works if I switch to the `Global` context, however I would like to have a separate context for each notebook. The question is then if you can add the notebook specific contexts to the autocomplete contexts?

Comment: Please give further explanation of the problem, I am willing to answer but I cant reproduce it or I dont understand. When I define a function testing[x_] and start writing te... I will get proposed testing. What else do you want? What Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @Philipp When I start typing `te` I don't get the proposed `testing` after defining `testing[x_]`. I just want that. I am using Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on OS X.

Comment: @Philipp The problem is the context, see the edit in the question.